# Orthonormal and/or Orthogonal Basis of a Pair of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

I was hoping someone could verify if this is the correct way to answer this problem:

Let $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ have the standard dot product.  Classify the following pair of vectors as (i) basis, (ii) orthogonal basis and/or, (iii) orthonormal basis:

$$
\vec{v_{1}} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \quad \vec{v_{2}} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

The way I did it was:

$$
\textbf{Basis:} \qquad \text{rref}\left( \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) \,\,=\,\, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \checkmark \\
\textbf{Orthogonal Basis:} \qquad \vec{v_{1}} \cdot \vec{v_{2}} \,\,=\,\, \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \,\,=\,\, 0 \quad \checkmark \\
\textbf{Orthonormal Basis:} \qquad \Vert\vec{v_{1}}\Vert \,\,=\,\,\sqrt{5} \qquad \Vert\vec{v_{2}}\Vert \,\,=\,\, \sqrt{5} \qquad \textbf{X}
$$

so this pair of vectors is classified as an $\boxed{\text{orthogonal basis}}$

I know that the final answer is correct from the back of the book that I got this problem from, but if I didn't get the solution the right way I would like to know where I went wrong.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Just note that in order for a set to form a basis, it must be linearly independent, and span the given space. It is easy to see in this example, but in further problems, you may need to verify manually.

Comment: Okay, my textbook is pretty vague so I followed PatrickJMT's video on Finding a Basis for a Set of Vectors (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0utd-Noc_Fs ) and he simply augments the set of vectors and puts it into reduced row echelon form.  What I took away from the video is that if the rref of the set of matrices is the identity matrix then the set forms a basis on the vector space, if not only the pivot columns of the original matrix form a basis.

Comment: Yes, take the columns from the original matrix corresponding to the pivot columns to form a basis.

Comment: Also, for technical purposes should I say $\vec{v_{1}}^{T} \cdot \vec{v_{2}}$ for the orthogonal basis?

Comment: No, is there a reason for this? Note that $\vec v_2^T \vec v_1$ is the matrix with one entry, $\vec v_1 \cdot \vec v_2$.

Comment: I was concerned about the "legality" of multiplying a $2 \times 1$ matrix with another $2 \times 1$ matrix. Maybe I am just confusing the dot product with matrix multiplication.

Comment: Remember: Dot product is an operation between two vectors which produces a scalar, and matrix multiplication is an operation on two matrices producing another matrix. In this very special case, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the matrices, and the product $v_1^Tv_2$, is the matrix with one entry containing the scalar dot product $v_1 \cdot v_2$.